# Second Quantisation, Fourier Transform, minus sign

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, second-quantization

I want to expand a field
\begin{equation}
  \Phi (x) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} e^{ipx}
\end{equation}
in terms of the second quantisation
\begin{equation}
  \Phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 E}}  (a + a^\dagger)
\end{equation}
The result must be 
\begin{equation}
  \Phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} (a e^{ipx} + a^\dagger e^{\textbf{-}ipx})
\end{equation}
and i do not know where the the minus sign in the second exponential is coming from? 
Is it because of the Dagger in the creation operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scalar Field Theory one defines creation and annihilation operators as:

$$a_p = E(p)\phi(p) + i\pi(p)$$ and 
$$ a^\dagger_p = E(−p)\phi(−p) − i\pi(−p)$$

combining together to give the momentum space representation of the quantum field:

$$ \tilde{\phi}(p) = \frac{a_p + a^\dagger_{-p}}{2E(p)}$$

By taking the Fourier transform of this momentum space quantum field we get an equivalent expression for the position space  representation which is:

$$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\tilde\phi(p)e^{ip·x} = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E(p)}e^{ip·x}(a_p + a^{\dagger}_{−p})$$

which can be split into two integrals in which we can identify the switching of variables from $p \to -p$ in the second integral, thus transforming it into:

$$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^32E(p)}a_pe^{ip·x}+ a^{\dagger}_{p}e^{-ip·x}$$